# How to count distinct ID by groups but keeping filter context - DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've encountered a problem, which I think should have easy fix but I'm completely stuck with this.

I have a table visual in PBIX with data restricted by DATE and Region filter - and I want to keep the filters.

[image]

I want to add a measure that would count distinct ID, grouped by Name, where status is CLOSED but disregard the date context within the visual (but keep it from slicer).

So for example something like this
For the row with name "Nina" status is "In Progress" so I have blank, for the "Maxim" name I want to have 1 since that Name has only one ID, but for "Huashu" I want to have 2 because this name has two distinct ID.

[image]

I was able to more or less achieve something similar but the problem is that when I'm using ALLSELECTED, ALL or ALLEXCEPT the visual returns all the possible rows and values and not restrict them by outer slicer filters (like here I have values only between 12/04/2023 and 10/07/2023.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Sound like calculate could help you with that.

What you want to do is count the number of IDs that are closed in this specific context that you have created.

Calculate will keep the row contexte when doing its calculation and adding a specific condition of your choosing:

```
Nb_ID = Countrows('MyTable'[ID])

Nb_ID_Closed = Calculate ([Nb ID],'MyTable'[Status] = "Closed")
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how calculate behaves. The problem with your answer is that it will overwrite every status only for closed and not group it. I have a problem with grouping not the behaviour or understanding calculate. I've mentioned that I used allselected which is a filter modifier so it needs to be used in calculate.

Comment: You can add an IF statement to hide the valued for all other rows
IF (Status = Closed,NB_ID, Blank())

Comment: That is not a proper way to hide not "closed". Better is Filter(VALUES) or KEEPFILTERS, which will restrict the status not overwrite it. But nevermind, I'm asking about completely different thing